# Show that the epigraph of $f(x) = 0, x < 0, \text{ and } 1, x\geq 0$ is not closed by examining a plot of the function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, graphing-functions

Given
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, x < 0\\
                     1, x\geq 0
       \end{cases}
\end{equation}

With the plot sketched below

[image]

> Show that the epigraph of this function defined as $$\text{epi}(f(x))
>  = \{(x,\alpha): f(x) \leq \alpha, x \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ is not closed.

Does anyone know if there is a way to reach this conclusion by just examining the plot?

The example is taken from
http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~cmcaram/EE381V_2012F/Lecture_18_Scribe_Notes.final.pdf

Comment: The plot makes it pretty clear that $f$ is not lower semicontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segment $\circ-\bullet$ is clearly a subset of $\operatorname{cl}{\operatorname{epi}f}$, but it is not a subset of $\operatorname{epi}f$.

**Added:** As an observation, the description of the original image in the notes states

> **Figure 18.4:** Example of a Function Whose Epigraph is Open.

That statement is incorrect, because $\operatorname{epi}f$ is not open either. In fact, as soon as $\operatorname{dom}f\ne\emptyset$, the epigraph of $f$ is guaranteed not to be open: if $f(x)=\alpha\in\Bbb R$, then $(x,\alpha)\in\operatorname{epi}f$ and $\left(x,\alpha-\frac1n\right)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow (x,\alpha)$. But $\left(x,\alpha-\frac1n\right)\notin \operatorname{epi}f$.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to explicitly write down $\text{epi}f$? What confuses me is that $\text{epi}f$ is a set consisting of pairs of values, how do you visualize this set?

Comment: It's the part of the plane which is above the graph of the function (graph included).

Comment: Okay I see now -_- its just like the graph of a function

Comment: It is true that any continuous function is lower semicontinuous and upper semicontinuous?

Comment: A real-valued function is continuous if ad only if it is both upper and lower semicontinuous.